# Java's static keyword cannot be used in embedded class's field?

Tags: java, class, static, field

I've got a xxx.java file and it has a package level class of:

```
class Foo<T> {
    public static int classVar = 1;
}
```

No problem, compiles, but if I wrap it into another class:

```
class Outer {
    class Foo<T> {
        public static int classVar = 2;
    }
}
```

Then it doesn't compile, saying that the `static` declaration of inner class Outer.foo is invalid, and `static` is only allowed in declaration of constant variable.

This syntax rule looks confuse to me----let's see from the Java language perspective, what would happen if `static` is allowed to be used like my program does? Will it lead to any ambiguous program? Or any Runtime problem?

Thanks for explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is right.

class *Foo* is not static, but dependent of instances of *Outer*.

That's the reason you could not statically access *classVar*, so this is not allowed because it would not make sense in any case.

What you could do instead is to make *Foo* static:

```
class Outer {
    static class Foo<T> {
        public static int classVar = 2;
    }
}
```

This way, one could **statically access** *classVar* like so: `Outer.Foo.classVar`.